# I want to implement progressbar while sending image

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to send the image through socket and while the sending process going on the progress bar must be displayed and it should be updating when the image is being sending but when i tried this code the progressbar is not been displayed and the image is being send.

```
  try {
        //image send
        client = new Socket(ServerIP,4444);

        File file = new File(path);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);     
                dos.writeUTF(file.getName()); 
                    int bytesread=0;

        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMessage("Sending...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setProgress(0);
        pd.show();

            while((bytesread=fis.read(mybytearray))>0)
                os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                int old_value=pd.getProgress();
                     int new_read=(int)( ((float)file.length()/bytesread));
                int value= new_read+old_value;
                pd.setProgress(value);
                pd.dismiss();
        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        bis.close();
        fis.close();
        client.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at AsyncTask for this type of task. try this following code and use for your requirement

```
public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowFullImageShare.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // write your code here for sending image
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {          
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

call this AsyncTask like this

```
new UploadImage().execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for Solution but I want to implement the the Horizontal Progressbar and if possible display it in notification

Comment: try to use Horizontal progress bar instead of this vertical progress bar.

Comment: I tried it but its getting 100 directly after sending image instead of it getting update while sending the image

Comment: use update method in asynctask it will update depending on the progress

Comment: can you give me example of that with respect to my sending image code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowFullImageShare.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Sending...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

while((bytesread=fis.read(mybytearray))>0)
os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
int old_value=pd.getProgress();
int new_read=(int)( ((float)file.length()/bytesread));
int value= new_read+old_value;
os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
os.flush();
bis.close();
fis.close();
client.close();

publishProgress(value);
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer progress) {          
    pDialog.setProgress(progress);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void value) {          
    pDialog.dismiss();

}
}
```